# Unable to connect to the database engine using SQL Server management studio

Tags: sql-server, installation

I installed SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU from Microsoft site on my Windows 7 Home Premium.
It gave me compatibility warnings but I still installed because Microsoft site specified that I would receive warnings but suggested to click on *Run Program*, which I did.

It was successfully installed. I checked *Services.msc*, and I can see two SQL Server services are running. I checked SQL Server Configuration, and I can see services running under automatic mode, and the agent is off.

When I open my management studio and try to connect using "Server name" option, I can't see any server instance in browse option. There are no servers to connect. I am not able to connect to the database engine. I have tried at least 10 times, but still, it's not allowing me to connect.

I get the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connectionto SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
```

allow remote connections.
    (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection 
    to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Is the firewall open between you and the server?  Try to telnet to the server over 1433.

Comment: What are the exact names of the two instances visible in Services.msc?  And are both started?

Comment: C:\Users\shilpa>sqlcmd -L Servers:[No server specified]

Comment: @RBarryYoung :- SQL Server (SQLExpress) and other is SQLServer (SQLServer2008)

Comment: @Siva Thanks... It got connected some how but gave below Error.
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyStore' threw an exception. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf)

Comment: And even it is not allowing me to create new database giving me again an error as 
Create failed for Database 'Shilpa'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the services applet says for the two instances (e.g. `SQL Server (Instance Name)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Connect to server* dialog of the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), type `<your machine name>\SQLServer2008` to connect to *SQLServer2008* instance. Otherwise, type `<your machine name`> alone in the server name text box to connect to the default instance *SQLExpress*.

Following link discusses how to fix the error *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyStore*

[**SSMS 2008 on Windows 7 throws exception when connecting Object Explorer**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/1115cd55-721d-4974-99b1-d142d1e6a927)

Comment: @ Siva: Thanku So much.... :))) that was so sweet of u.It worked for SQLServerExpress Instance I m able to create databse tables even tried to access tables from VS2010. And above link specifies to copy file "microsoft.sqlserver.diagnostics.strace" which i dnt find nywhr in my C:\ so Shud i repair my VS2010??